# Can you getContext of text value?

Tags: javascript, css, html

So I have an input form that needs to be not visible for a certain point. So I use CSS and Javascript to hide the input until it should be visible. I come from a python background and what I would like to do is something like:

```
name = input("")
```

I tried to do something like that but it just assigns the change in visibility to the variable. I have tried using .value however I just can't it to work properly.

I was wondering if you can get can getContext (or if there is something similar) that allows me to assign what the user. Or I could just simply append it to a variable for it work as it should.

[To give additional context I need the form to get the value the user has inputted when they click submit on the canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgPQd.png)

```js
var gameOver = true;
if (gameOver){
  document.getElementById('name').style.visibility = 'visible'
  console.log(name)
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <input id = "name" type="text" class="name"
          style="visibility: hidden;"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by simply declaring a variable, say `var nameInput`, and then assigning the DOM node to it:

```
var nameInput = document.getElementById('name');
```

Note that you should *not* be using `name`, because it is an [implementation-dependent reserved keyword in JavaScript](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm).

To access its style object, you can simply use `nameInput.style...`, e.g. `nameInput.style.visibility = 'visible'` if you want to update the `visibility` property.

If you want to retrieve it's value, you can do this:

```
console.log(nameInput.value);
```

```js
var gameOver = true;
if (gameOver) {
  var nameInput = document.getElementById('name');
  nameInput.style.visibility = 'visible';
  console.log('DOM node: ' + nameInput);
  console.log('Value: ' + nameInput.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="name" type="text" class="name" style="visibility: hidden;" />
```

If you want to dynamically retrieve its value as the user inputs it, you will need to read up on event binding using `.addEventListener()`. JS is **not reactive** in the sense that you dynamically update variables upon user interaction with the page. The regime is this:

1. User triggers some kind of event. In this case, you want to listen to the `onInput`, `onChange`, `onBlur`... events
2. In your JS logic, you will have to listen to this event that is emitted by the element. This is done by binding an event listener to your DOM node.

```js
var gameOver = true;
if (gameOver) {
  var nameInput = document.getElementById('name');
  nameInput.style.visibility = 'visible';
  console.log('DOM node: ' + nameInput);
  console.log('Value: ' + nameInput.value);
}

nameInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
  console.log('Updated value: ' + this.value);
});
```

```html
<input id="name" type="text" class="name" style="visibility: hidden;" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it seems to console log it before I've inputted anything in the box, so Value is always ""

Comment: @user8570650 That is because JS is not reactive. If you want to get the value when a user has inputted something, you need to [bind event listeners to it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Answer (score 0):

If I properly understand your question, your problem right now is to get the input value because you already have the code to make it visible.

So what you need to do is to add a handler to your input to execute a function in the moment you want to retrieve the value the user types-in, for instance on change:

HTML:

```
<input id = "name" type="text" class="name"
      style="visibility: hidden;" onchange="inputChanged();"></input>
```

Javascript:

```
function inputChanged() {
  console.log(document.getElementById('name').value);
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: You shouldn't be using inline JS to bind event listeners.